# When adding a jQuery Accordion element, need new element to default open

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have an accordion where I'm dynamically creating new elements.  However, when I do I cannot seem to get the newest element to default to open.  It's always the first element.

Ideas?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <asp:MultiView ID="MainView" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            <table style="width: 100%; border-width: 3px; border-color: #C4F691; border-style: solid">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="rowClassSpace">
                            &nbsp;</div>
                        <div id="accordion">
                            <a href="#">Make/Model (Insured Vehicle)</a>
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        Content
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="addAccordion">
                                Add Another Vehicle</button>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
```

Here's the JS:

```
    //  Initialize accordion
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        });
     });

    //  Adding according sections
    $('#addAccordion').click(function () {
    });

    function addAccordion() {
       var active = $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active');
       $('#accordion').append('<a href="#">Make/Model (Other Car #)</a><div><p>New data</p></div>').accordion('destroy').accordion({ active: active});
       }
```

Comment: When are you adding the accordion elements.  It could very well be that you are adding the dynamic accordion elements after you are calling .accordion().

Answer (score 1):

Suggest using `destroy` method to destroy existing, then append new section, then initialize new accordion instance. Also markup you are using seems strange using `<a>` tags

By counting existing sections you can set the `active` index to number of sections before the new one is added so that newest section added will be opened

```
var template=function(ctr){
   /* using html markup per docs*/
    return '<h3>Section '+ctr+'</h3><div>Content '+ctr+'</div>';
};

var accordOptions={
    collapsible:true,
    active:0
};
var $accord=$('#accordion').accordion(accordOptions);

$('button').click(  addSection);

function addSection(){
    var num_sections=$accord.children('h3').length;
    /* set active index to number of current sections*/
    accordOptions.active=num_sections;
    $accord.accordion('destroy')
            .append( template( num_sections +1 ) )
            .accordion( accordOptions);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HnVqD/